# How to debug salt.states.pip.installed?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, setuptools, salt-stack

I have a salt state that does a pip install -r requirements.txt within a virtualenv. It crashes due to a UnicodeDecodeError when copying a script to {venv}/bin for one particular *develop* package.

```
Running setup.py develop for pymantic
    Complete output from command /home/michaels/webapps/test/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/michaels/webapps/test/src/pymantic/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps:
    running develop
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to pymantic.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing pymantic.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pymantic.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pymantic.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to pymantic.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pymantic.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pymantic.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    Creating /home/michaels/webapps/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymantic.egg-link (link to .)
    Adding pymantic 0.2.0dev-r0 to easy-install.pth file
    Installing named_graph_to_nquads script to /home/michaels/webapps/test/bin
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/michaels/webapps/test/src/pymantic/setup.py", line 38, in <module>
        'pymantic/scripts/bnf2html',
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/michaels/webapps/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 34, in run
        self.install_for_development()
      File "/home/michaels/webapps/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 133, in install_for_development
        self.process_distribution(None, self.dist, not self.no_deps)
      File "/home/michaels/webapps/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 697, in process_distribution
        self.install_egg_scripts(dist)
      File "/home/michaels/webapps/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 168, in install_egg_scripts
        script_text = strm.read()
      File "/home/michaels/webapps/test/lib/python2.7/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 59: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried to reproduce the error outside of salt, but I haven't been able to. I tried:

1. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
2. `python setup.py develop`
3. `python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;…` (see the top of the traceback)

I tried the above both within and outside of the virtualenv, with both fresh and existing installs. Most searches I've tried have shown UnicodeDecodeError writing to the *log*, but this seems to be from reading a particular file. I'm at a loss what to try next, and I haven't been able to figure out how to drop into Salt to figure out what it's doing different from me.

Here're the relevant salt states:

```
# Create apps virtualenv, install requirements on change to repo
{{ user }}-{{ repo }}-apps-virtualenv:
  virtualenv.managed:
    - name: /home/{{ user }}/webapps/{{ repo }}
    - cwd: /home/{{ user }}/webapps/{{ repo }}/src/app
    - system_site_packages: False
    - user: {{ user }}
    - require:
      - git: {{ user }}-{{ repo }}-apps-repo
{{ user }}-{{ repo }}-apps-requirements:
  pip.installed:
    - bin_env: /home/{{ user }}/webapps/{{ repo }}/bin/pip
    - cwd: /home/{{ user }}/webapps/{{ repo }}/src/app
    - requirements: /home/{{ user }}/webapps/{{ repo }}/src/app/requirements.txt
    - user: {{ user }}
    - require:
      - virtualenv: {{ user }}-{{ repo }}-apps-virtualenv
    - watch:
      - git: {{ user }}-{{ repo }}-apps-repo
    - env_vars:
      - LC_ALL: en_US.UTF-8
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: Interesting one! I'm sure this must be recreateable outside Salt- the stack trace is all distutils and setuptools. Can you update your Q to include the requirements.txt?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably down to different locale/env settings when running under different user envs. Try running using salt-call. Assuming you have virtualenvwrapper installed :

`mkvirtualenv foo
salt-call --local --log-level  debug  pip.install pkgs=slugify bin_env=$HOME/.virtualenvs/foo`

Then try the same using sudo / sudo su root or whatever user/env your salt-minion is running under. Also, try running minion on foreground. Finally, when using salt-call, you can simply insert a pdb breakpoint in the pip.py salt module and inspect the situation.